# I broke a fixed broken window

Tags: sentence-construction

> I broke a fixed broken window.

Is it a semantically and grammatically correct sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an oxymoron. One cannot have  "*a fixed broken window*"

You can have

a window that has been fixed.
a window that was broken but has now been fixed

> you ***can break a window that had been previously repaired after being broken.***

but ***you cannot say you  broke a fixed broken window.*** because **you would have to break it** anyway.

Confused? Well can you break something that is broken?

Comment: I thought it’s similar to a half of half an hour is 15 minutes.

Comment: I think now a half of half an hour is grammatically incorrect.